# How risky is it to call Await.result on db calls

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

When using phantom how dangerous is it to be following this pattern in db calls:

```
Await.result(dbOperationFut, 30.seconds)
```

This isn't really phantom specific but it is the scala driver being used.

I am weary of this pattern because of the potential GC pause that might last for over x seconds.  How many seconds is safe given GC pauses?

I am personally in favor of using for-comp and not blocking like this, but just want to know if this is a REALLY bad practice or it is fine.

**Context**:  This would be for akka based applications (akka, akka http)

Thoughts?

Comment: Await.result is highly discouraged outside of testing.

Comment: I don't really see what could be risky about it. The only downside is that it's blocking.

Comment: Following on from @AndyHayden and Jasper-M comments, there is really only one time you should ever consider using *Await*. That's when you have your own main program (not so common in practice) and you just don't want to exit until you've got your answer. In all other situations you should be able to compose your *Future* objects together using for comprehension or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Becareful with Await.result**

*Note this applies for both Akka and play apps*

> *`Await.result` should be used very carefully only when it is absolutely necessary.*

`Await.result` blocks the thread in which it is running until the given duration. Blocking the thread will waste the precious computation resource because that thread will not be able to do any useful computation like handling the new request or number crunching in an algorithm etc.

So, Avoid using the `Await.result` as much as possible.

> But, when do we use it (Await.result) ?

Here is one of the typical use case for using `Await.result`.

Lets say you have written a program containing main thread and all the computation inside the main thread is asynchronous. Now once you start the asynchronous computation inside the main thread. Some one has to stop the main thread from existing till the asynchronous computation finishes, if not the program stops running and you cannot see the result of the asynchronous computation.

> When an application begins running, there is one non-daemon thread, whose job is to execute main(). JVM will not exit by itself until and unless non-daemon threads are completed.

```
object Main {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  val f = Future { //do something }
  //stop main thread till f completes
  Await.result(f, 10 seconds)
 }
}
```

> Future uses daemon threads for running. So daemon threads cannot stop the JVM from shutting down. So JVM shuts down even if non-daemon threads are running.

In the above case there is no other way expect stopping (blocking) the main thread till the computation `f` completes if not main thread exits and computation stops.

> In most of the cases you do not need to use `Await.result` and simple `Future` composition using `map` and `flatMap` would suffice.

**Risks of using Await.result (In general all blocking code)**

> *Running out of threads in event based model*

In event based model you will quickly run out of threads if you have blocking code which takes long time to return. In playframework any blocking call could decrease the performance of the application and app will becomes dead slow as it runs out of threads.

> *Running out of memory in non-event based models*

In thread per request models. When you have blocking calls which take long time to exit/return.

*case 1: If you have fixed thread pool then application might run out of threads.*

*case 2: If you have dynamically growing thread pool then your application will suffer from too much context switching overhead and also will run out of memory because of too many blocked threads in memory.*

In all of the cases no useful work is done expect for waiting for some IO or some other event.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of whether or not `Await.result` poses any kind of risk...

Comment: @Jasper-M updated the answer with risks. Please feel free to point out out any errors and unclear info. So that i can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Just for more detail, this would be a akka application not play.

Comment: @coolbreeze same applies for akka. Avoid blocking every where even in akka.

Comment: @coolbreeze this applies for all the apps in general (both play and akka apps)

Comment: @pamu One question, I have a library which does a REST call and returns the result as a future and I need the result of that REST call to proceed any further. Will it be appropriate in such a scenario to use Await.result?