# Alternative to await.ready

Tags: scala

I have the following code in Scala:

```
val status: Future[String] = Await.ready(Http(address OK as.String), 1 second)
```

I'm making a `http` call and I'm waiting for an answer for a second.

I was told it's not good practice to block using `Await.ready`.

I'm curious what I can use instead.

Can I use for comprehensions? How?

Comment: I assume that you mean `Await.result` as the above won't even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It generally bad to block on an asynchronous operation, otherwise, why make it asynchronous at all?

You can use various implementations with `Future[T]`, such as *registering a continuation* to invoke when the result arrives. For example, let's assume you want to parse the `String` result into a `Foo` object. You'd get:

```
val result: Future[Foo] = Http(address OK as.String).map {
  s => parseJson[Foo](s)
}
```

Note that when working with `Future[T]`, you'll end up bubbling them up the call chain of the execution, unless you synchronously block.

Same can be achieved with for comprehension:

```
for {
 s <- Http(address OK as.String)
} yield (parseJson[Foo](s))
```

Comment: Thanks! I would like to wait for a limited amount of time though(for instance, maximum 1 second). How can I do that?

Comment: @octavian [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16305056/1870803) shows you how to add an extension of timeout to a `Future`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Await.ready` is not a good practice because its blocking. In most of the cases you can compose and transform the futures to achieve the desired result.

But You can use blocking when its absolutely necessary. Here is my answer about blocking and its consequences [When to and when not use blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795109/how-risky-is-it-to-call-await-result-on-db-calls/40802058#40802058)

**Non-Blocking wait**

```
def afterSomeTime(code: => Unit)(duration: FiniteDuration): Unit = {
  someActorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(duration) {
    code
  }
}
```

Above function will call the code after given duration, you can use any other timer implementation instead of Akka scheduler

```
case class TimeoutException(msg: String) extends Exception(msg)

def timeout[T](future: => Future[T])(duration: FiniteDuration)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {

  val promise = Promise[T]()
  future.onComplete(promise tryComplete)

  afterSomeTime {
    promise tryFailure TimeoutException(s"Future timeout after ${duration.toString()}")
  }(duration)

  promise.future
}
```